# Environment URLs not recognized by Puppet Master service

Tags: apache, passenger, puppet

I set up a Puppet Master with Passenger and Apache according to the [documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/passenger.html). I also have the "environmentspath" variable set in the puppet.conf on the master, and I created a "production" environment directory. My Puppet Agent has its puppet.conf "environment" variable set to "production" as well.

However, when I run "puppet agent --test", for example, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not request certificate: Find /production/certificate/ca?fail_on_404=true resulted in 404 with the message: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /production/certificate/ca was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at <server>.<domain> Port 8140</address>
</body></html>
```

I made the server and domain in the error above anonymous for the purposes of this post, and port 8140 is just the standard port used by Puppet.

I'm running Phusion Passenger version 4.0.50. Has anyone seen this error before? I'm sure it's something simple I missed during the Puppet Master installation, but I've been through the [install docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/pre_install.html) multiple times with no luck.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there's any additional information I should provide to help solve this.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the VHost configuration. I've made anonymous any references to host names or domains.

```
# You'll need to adjust the paths in the Passenger config depending on which OS
# you're using, as well as the installed version of Passenger.

# RHEL/CentOS:
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.50/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.50
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby

# And the passenger performance tuning settings:
# Set this to about 1.5 times the number of CPU cores in your master:
PassengerMaxPoolSize 3
# Recycle master processes after they service 1000 requests
PassengerMaxRequests 1000
# Stop processes if they sit idle for 10 minutes
PassengerPoolIdleTime 600

Listen 8140
<VirtualHost *:8140>
    # Make Apache hand off HTTP requests to Puppet earlier, at the cost of
    # interfering with mod_proxy, mod_rewrite, etc. See note below.
    PassengerHighPerformance On

    SSLEngine On

    # Only allow high security cryptography. Alter if needed for compatibility.
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:CAMELLIA256-$
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

    SSLCertificateFile      /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/<server>.<domain>.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/<server>.<domain>.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile    /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
    SSLCARevocationFile     /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem
#   SSLCARevocationCheck        chain
    SSLVerifyClient         optional
    SSLVerifyDepth          1
    SSLOptions              +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

    # Apache 2.4 introduces the SSLCARevocationCheck directive and sets it to none
        # which effectively disables CRL checking. If you are using Apache 2.4+ you must
    # specify 'SSLCARevocationCheck chain' to actually use the CRL.

    # These request headers are used to pass the client certificate
    # authentication information on to the puppet master process
    RequestHeader set X-SSL-Subject %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
    RequestHeader set X-Client-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
    RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}e

    DocumentRoot /etc/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public

    <Directory /etc/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/>
      Options None
      AllowOverride None
      # Apply the right behavior depending on Apache version.
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" puppet
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/puppet.log puppet
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/<server>.<domain>.pem_ssl_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/<server>.<domain>.pem_ssl_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think this should move to ServerFault, because your issue is with the Apache configuration. - The Passenger module is not configured correctly. Apache tries to serve the request from the filesystem, which is bound to fail. Needs Apache error logs at restart and excerpts from the :8140 vhost that you think should activate and configure Passenger for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "this should move to ServerFault"?

Comment: The question is nearly off topic, and more appropriate to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), because it deals with server operations rather than programming. - So does `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.50/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so` exist? Is there any indication in the server log when the agent checks in or at Apache startup?

Comment: There could have been a mod_passenger.so file at the time (right now there's only a mod_passenger.c file), but I've since rolled back to version 3.0.9 of Passenger because I read that 4.0.50 was no longer compatible with Puppet environments. The file `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so` does exist and the older version of Passenger seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how to move this question to the ServerFault site. I know it's possible but maybe I don't have enough reputation? I don't even see a way to vote that it should be moved. I could flag the moderator to move it, but I'll probably just close this question since it's no longer relevant.

Comment: Yes. I did flag it as OT just now.

Answer (score 2):

DevOps... That nice line right between ServerFault and StackOverflow... : )

I had the same issue with an install of Puppet/Apache/Passenger on a CentOS 6.5 Puppet Master with both Ubuntu and CentOS Puppet Agent servers.

Turned out that my issue was that **SELinux** had locked down my Apache instance **even though I had turned it into *Permissive* mode** in the **/etc/sysconfig/selinux** file. For some reason that file wasn't linked to the "real" **/etc/selinux/config** file so it stayed in *Enforcing* mode once I rebooted and didn't allow Passenger to run and many other necessary operations that need to be allowed between the Puppet Master and the Puppet Agent computers.

Here is how I fixed it on the Puppet Master:

```
#Set SELinux into Permissive mode for current session
sudo setenforce permissive

#Set SELinux into Permissive mode for reboots
sudo sed –i ‘s\=enforcing\=permissive\g’ /etc/selinux/config

#REBOOT and Verify Current Mode
sudo getenforce
    Permissive
```

Your puppet agents should now be able to negotiate a connection and perform the Certificate Signing Request that the Puppet Master will have to reply to.

Later, when the Puppet Master had audited all the operations needed so that I could turn SELinux back into *Enforcing* mode (i.e. downloading manifests and executing package/service/file operations on the Puppet Agent boxes) I replayed the audit log and turned SELinux back on and verified that the puppet agents had no issues communicating. You might not want to replay the full audit log, but you get the idea.

```
#Install Audit2Allow
sudo yum –y install policycoreutils-python

#Build a policy package for allowing passenger/puppet to run
sudo grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M passenger
sudo semodule -i passenger.pp

#Once done, re-enable SELinux
sudo setenforce 1
sudo sed -i 's\=permissive\=enforcing\g' /etc/selinux/config

#REBOOT and Verify Current Mode
getenforce
    Enforcing
```

On the Puppet Agent Server:

```
#Verify Puppet Agents can communicate with no issues.
sudo puppet agent --verbose --no-daemonize --onetime
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The issue was "/etc/selinux/config" file missing the permissive mode.